# Append last n nodes of a singly LL to the start

Tags: c++, linked-list

Please help me find the error in the given code, After returning the new head and using the printing function, no output gets displayed

```
Node *interChange(Node *head, int n){
    Node *tempoo = head;
    Node *temp = head;
    int tot =0;
    
    while(tempoo != NULL){
        tempoo = tempoo->next;
        tot++;
    }
   
    
    int count =0;
    
    while(count < tot-n){
        temp=temp->next;
        count++;
    }
    Node *newHead = temp->next;
    temp->next=NULL;
    Node *newTemp = newHead;
    
    while(newTemp != NULL){
        newTemp = newTemp->next;
    }
    newTemp->next = head;
    
    return newHead;
    
}
```

Comment: *"and using the printing function"* -- what printing function? Please see [mre].

Comment: Maybe you are calling `Node *interChange(Node *head, int n)` wrongly. Remember that you are passing a copy of the `head` pointer to the function and it returns the updated `head` if you throw that away then `head` won't change.

Answer (score 1):

The last statement before the `return` performs an invalid dereferencing: `newTemp->next = head;` when at that point it is guaranteed that `newTemp` is `NULL`. This leads to undefined behaviour.

Your function *returns* the new head, so make sure the caller (which you didn't include) will use that new head pointer when printing the list.

Some other remarks:

- The code does not deal well when the list is empty
- The code does not deal well when `n` is greater than the number of nodes in the list, or is negative. It would maybe be a good idea to use modulo arithmetic to bring that value in range.
- The cutoff point is wrongly calculated. For `n` is 0, the original head node will still become the new tail (if all the rest is corrected).
- In C++ you should be using `nullptr` instead of `NULL`
- Calling all your variables something like `temp` is not helpful. You can do with fewer variables, and use more telling names.

Here is a correction to your function:

```
Node *interChange(Node *head, int n) {
    if (head == nullptr) return nullptr; // Boundary case
    Node *tail = head;
    int tot = 1; // We already have the head
    // Check whether there is a next node, so we end up with the tail
    while (tail->next != nullptr) {
        tail = tail->next;
        tot++;
    }
    // Make list circular
    tail->next = head;
    // Bring the n argument within a valid range 
    n %= tot;
    // Find new tail
    for (int count = tot - n; count; count--) {
        tail = tail->next; // Reuse tail variable to identify new tail
    }
    // Reuse variable to identify new head
    head = tail->next;
    // Make list non-circular again
    tail->next = nullptr;
    return head;
}
```

The caller should capture the returned pointer. For instance:

```
Node *head;
// Initialise head with a list ...
// (your code here)
// And then:
head = interChange(head, 3);
```